# ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)

Tags: 16.04, mysql

I have installed MySQL Server via the command line:

```
sudo apt-get install mysql-server
```

But then when I run

```
sudo mysql -u root -p
```

I get the following error

```
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)
```

I have searched a lot about this but nothing has solved my problem

Comment: You might find this related post at our sister site useful: https://superuser.com/questions/603026/mysql-how-to-fix-access-denied-for-user-rootlocalhost

Comment: When I tried to do step 1 in the accepted answer in this post 
`mysql --skip-grant-tables`
I get this error
`mysqld: Can't change dir to '/var/lib/mysql/' (Errcode: 13 - Permission denied)`

Comment: There's a great deal more information there than simply the accepted answer (which I believe indicates that a password has been setup.) Perhaps in your case [this](https://superuser.com/questions/1060360/how-to-have-mysql-entitle-the-machines-root-user) will be more useful.